# Filling “symbolic y coords” automatically with the content of a table row

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to fill “symbolic y coords” automatically with the content of a table row? I have many data to plot and it would be very cumbersome and laborious to do it manually.

Best regards

Christoph

Comment: I wouldn't use symbolic coordinates in this case, but `x expr=\coordindex` in combination with `xtick=data, xticklabels from table={<table macro>}{<column with labels>}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use symbolic coordinates for something like this, because they're much less comfortable to use than "proper" coordinates. You can simply plot the data using `x expr=\coordindex` and add the labels from the table using `xtick=data, xticklabels from table={<table macro>}{<column with labels>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{
      23, Einhaltung der Hygienestandards
      20, Zeitintensität des Programms
      18, Zubereitung des O+G
      16, Lagerung des O+G
      7, Müllentsorgung und Reinigung
      6, Sonstige
      4, Keine Probleme
      4, Abstimmung mit dem Lieferanten/Warennahme/Lieferzeitpunkt
      1, Verteilung des O+G auf die Klassen
      1, Qualität der Lieferung/Lieferung an zwei aufeinanderfolgenden Tagen ist schlecht/bessere Verteilung
      1, Keine Lieferung an allen Schultagen/nach Ferien öfters holpriger Beginn
      1, Auswahl des Obstes
      1, Ausstattung mit Materialien (Schneidebrett)
      1, Anmeldung zum SOP
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar, %
    y=-1.5cm,%
    bar width=0.5cm,%
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.45cm},
    xlabel={Häufigkeit},%
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{1},
    ytick=data,%
    yticklabel style={text width=5cm,align=right},%
    nodes near coords,%
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},%
    ]%
    \addplot table [y expr=\coordindex, x=0] {\datatable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```